# Reference request: for well-pointed spaces, the join and the reduced join are homotopy equivalent

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, reference-request

I noticed a claim that for well-pointed spaces $X$ and $Y$, their join and reduced join are homotopy equivalent.

I would like to know a reference for this fact.

Thanks in advance!